# What is the difference between text and pg_catalog.text?

Tags: postgresql, schema, datatypes

I have a classic 3-environments setting (dev, staging and production), each with its own [RDS PostgreSQL 9.3](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/postgresql/). The client/server versions are `psql (9.3.5, server 9.3.3)`.

In order to keep the schemas aligned, I have a periodic schema diff job, which notifies me when the schemas differ.

A few days ago, I started getting many of these diffs:

```
CREATE TABLE ...
...
<     title pg_catalog.text,
<     subtitle pg_catalog.text,
---
>     title text,
>     subtitle text,
```

The `text` fields in staging was somehow converted to `pg_catalog.text` in prod.

**What is the difference between `text` and `pg_catalog.text`? How can I equate the two schemas?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are the **same thing** in a default installation.

`pg_catalog.text` is the schema-qualified version of the type name `text`.

The `search_path` ***always*** contains `pg_catalog` automatically. [Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-CATALOG)

> In addition to `public` and user-created schemas, each database contains
>   a `pg_catalog` schema, which contains the system tables and all the
>   built-in data types, functions, and operators. `pg_catalog` is always
>   effectively part of the search path. If it is not named explicitly in
>   the path then it is implicitly searched before searching the path's
>   schemas. This ensures that built-in names will always be findable.
>   However, **you can explicitly place `pg_catalog` at the end of your search
>   path if you prefer to have user-defined names override built-in names.**

Bold emphasis mine. If you do such a thing, Postgres will automatically start schema-qualifying names in text-representation, that would otherwise be resolved differently. That's most probably what you see. Check your current `search_path` with:

```
SHOW search_path;
```

Closely related:

- [How can I fake inet_client_addr() for unit tests in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69988/how-can-i-fake-inet-client-addr-for-unit-tests-in-postgresql/70009#70009)
- [How to create table inside specific schema by default in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067777/939860)