# Is it recommended to install extensions into pg_catalog schema?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, best-practices, postgresql-extensions

Since objects in `pg_catalog` schema are implicitly in the `search_path` ([docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-CATALOG)), would it be recommended to install extensions in that schema?

Answer (score 18):

Don't install extensions to `pg_catalog` (unless that's their default: very few extensions are designed that way), because you don't mess with system catalog, ***ever***. [@Chris](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/107406/3684) demonstrates one reason why. There are others.

However, the **"public" schema is in no way special**. It's just the default schema that's pre-installed in standard distributions so we can get started right away. Some DB admins don't use the "public" schema at all, some even delete it.

**`CREATE EXTENSION`** is not affiliated to the "public" schema. It installs into the *current schema* unless instructed otherwise - except some extensions have a pre-set schema (like [PGQ / Londiste](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PGQ_Tutorial)). [The documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createextension.html)

> ***schema_name***
>
> The name of the schema in which to install the extension's objects,
>   given that the extension allows its contents to be relocated. The
>   named schema must already exist. If not specified, and the extension's
>   control file does not specify a schema either, **the current default
>   object creation schema is used**.
>
> Remember that the extension itself is not considered to be within any
>   schema: extensions have unqualified names that must be unique
>   database-wide. But objects belonging to the extension can be within schemas.

Bold emphasis mine.
Decide how to manage users, schemas and the **`search_path`**:

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the “current schema”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067777/939860)

*Then* decide where to install extensions. You can install to any schema of your choice and include that schema in the default `search_path` for all users or just for some or no users at all (so that qualified references are required). It all depends on what you want to achieve.
Whatever you do, stay consistent.

I like to install extensions (that allow it) in a dedicated "extensions" schema, which I include in the default `search_path` *after* "public" (and "$user" - if you use that). Helps with a clean separation of my own public functions and other public objects. My setting in `postgresql.conf`:

```
search_path = "$user",public,extensions
```

Or:

```
search_path = public,extensions
```

And I install extensions with:

```
CREATE EXTENSION some_extension SCHEMA extensions;
```

One thing to note: This way you can "hide" (unqualified) objects in the `extensions` schema behind objects of the same name (and parameters) in the `public` schema.

Related:

- [Best way to install hstore on multiple schemas in a Postgres database?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19146824/939860)
- [How can I fake inet_client_addr() for unit tests in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69988/how-can-i-fake-inet-client-addr-for-unit-tests-in-postgresql/70009#70009)

Comment: ok is ```plpgsql``` extension then somehow an exception to this rule? Every install I have seen has this extension in pg_catalog

Comment: @zam6ak: Yes, plpgsql is a bit of a special case: [Quoting the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-overview.html): `In PostgreSQL 9.0 and later, PL/pgSQL is installed by default. However it is still a loadable module, so especially security-conscious administrators could choose to remove it.`

Comment: plv8 installs itself to `pg_catalog`, too. (It throws an error if you try to change it.) Is this maybe a standard for installing procedural language extensions for functions?

Answer (score 8):

Installing extensions into `pg_catalog` are, as far as I'm aware, not advised.  You should use the default `public` schema, which is also in the `search_path` by default.

## **Why?**

As an example, I will work with the `pageinspect` extension which I've already created within the `public` schema.  All functions are, by default, accessible to all schemas in the database if they are located in the `public` schema.

Now, I try moving it to the `pg_catalog` schema, using

```
ALTER EXTENSION pageinspect SET SCHEMA pg_catalog;
```

and it works just fine.

But...

Try to move it again, back to the `public` schema using

```
ALTER EXTENSION pageinspect SET SCHEMA public;
```

and it won't permit it, yielding the following error

```
ERROR: cannot remove dependency on schema pg_catalog because it is a system object
SQL state: 0A000
```

Uh oh!  Well, that's OK that it won't let me move it.  I can just get it back into the `public` schema by dropping it and re-creating, right?...

```
DROP EXTENSION pageinspect;
CREATE EXTENSION pageinspect;
```

OK, good.  Back in it's right place in the `public` schema, and the functions are still accessible to all schemas in the database.

**TL,DR;** Just use the default `public` schema for extensions.