# Connect as postgres user on AWS RDS to install extension to pg_catalog

Tags: postgresql, permissions, amazon-rds, postgresql-extensions

I need to connect to our AWS RDS PostgreSQL 9.5 instance so I can add the `citext` extension to `pg_catalog` schema so it is available to all schemas (PG prepends `pg_catalog` to the beginning of the `search_path` by default).

I'm easily able to do this on my local machine:

```
> sudo su - postgres
> psql
> \c mydatabase
> CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS citext SCHEMA pg_catalog;
> \q
> exit
```

If I login to the RDS using a direct connection as AWS docs show, I am given `permission denied for schema pg_catalog` when I try to `CREATE EXTENSION`:

```
psql
   --host=myrdsawshostname
   --port=5432
   --username=myusername
   --password
   --dbname=mydatabase
```

This is the only way I know how to connect and I can only seem to connect as "myusername" not "postgres".

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you tried  as "CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS citext" without giving any schema ?

Comment: What is `available to all schemas` supposed to mean. It does no make sense in Postgres terminology. Maybe you mean `available to all users`?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I'm actually referring to what I learned from another post of yours `The system schemas pg_temp (schema for temporary objects of the current session) and pg_catalog are automatically part of the search path and searched first, in this order.` Did I misinterpret in this context? http://stackoverflow.com/a/9067777/1161463

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter to clarify, I mean I want the extensions I add to be available for use in all schemas that come after the schema that has that extension in the `search_path`. I think your answer gives a safer solution to this.

Comment: @eComEvo: The `search_path` decides visibility of objects. Schemas in Postgres are much (but not completely!) like directories in a file system in this respect, and the `search_path` much like the directory search path in the OS. If an object is visible, it is available for use in *any* schema. See: [What is the search path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-does-the-search-path-influence-identifier-resolution-and-the-current-schema/9067777#9067777)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt to write to the `pg_catalog` schema probably fails because you don't have a superuser on RDS, just a role with limited admin privileges. And Amazon is smart enough to prevent users from messing with the system catalogs. I.e.: [no `CREATE` privilege in the schema `pg_catalog`.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html)

It's ***generally not advisable*** to install additional modules like `citext` into the `pg_catalog` system schema. (Some exceptions have the schema preset.) Install it to `public` or some dedicated schema.

- [Is it recommended to install extensions into pg_catalog schema?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107389/is-it-recommended-to-install-extensions-into-pg-catalog-schema)

The "home" schema of the installed extension needs to be in the `search_path`. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/citext.html)

> The schema containing the `citext` operators must be in the current
> `search_path` (typically `public`); if it is not, the normal
> case-sensitive `text` operators will be invoked instead.

You can easily set the `search_path` for one / some / all users or databases or user / database combinations or temporarily or for the current session or generally:

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the “current schema”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067777/939860)