# Postgres: ERROR: operator does not exist: point <@> point

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-extensions, postgresql-11

Using PostgreSQL 11 on Windows.

Both `cube` and `earthdistance` installed and verified by `pg_available_extensions`.

Restarted PostgreSQL.

> ```
> [42883] ERROR: operator does not exist: point <@> point.
> ```

Setup:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS cube SCHEMA temp;
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS earthdistance SCHEMA temp;
```

Tried the [following code from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10035296)

```
create table temp.lat_lon (
  city varchar(50) primary key,
  lat float8 not null,
  lon float8 not null
);

insert into temp.lat_lon values
('London, GB', 51.67234320, 0.14787970),
('New York, NY', 40.91524130, -73.7002720);

select
  (
  (select point(lon,lat) from temp.lat_lon where city = 'London, GB') <@>
  (select point(lon,lat) from temp.lat_lon where city = 'New York, NY')
  ) as distance_miles;
```

Throws:

> ```
> [42883] ERROR: operator does not exist: point <@> point.
> ```

Extensions installed and Postgres was restarted.

`select * from pg_available_extensions where name IN ('cube', 'earthdistance');`

```
cube            1.4     data type for multidimensional cubes
earthdistance   1.1     calculate great-circle distances on the surface of the Earth
```

Is this because of PostgreSQL v11 on Windows? Yes, Lat/Long in correct order (long is first).

Note: [Table F.6 Point-based Earthdistance Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/earthdistance.html)

Update in regards to: schema / search path:

```
SELECT extname, extnamespace::regnamespace FROM pg_extension
WHERE  extname IN ('cube', 'earthdistance');

cube            temp
earthdistance   temp
```

```
SHOW search_path;

temp
```

Note: I `CREATE EXTENSION hstore SCHMEA temp;` and can use `hstore` and its operators. So doesn't seem to be all extensions.

Comment: Just wanted to turn you onto PostGIS if you never heard of it. It does a lot more, and the indexing is better than Earthdistance.

Comment: Thanks @EvanCarroll `PostGIS` is a little too much for this particular usage. Only sparingly need to use `earthdistance <@>`. If the project evolves to needing more geo, `PostGIS` is the next option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible explanation: you installed the extension in a **schema** that's missing from your current **`search_path`**.

Diagnose with:

```
SELECT extname, extnamespace::regnamespace FROM pg_extension
WHERE  extname IN ('cube', 'earthdistance');

SHOW search_path;
```

Is the schema of the extensions in your current `search_path`? If not, there is your explanation. Either install to a different schema or adapt your `search_path`.

And:

```
SELECT oprnamespace::regnamespace, oprleft::regtype, oprname, oprright::regtype
FROM   pg_operator
WHERE  oprname = '<@>';
```

Related:

- [Is it recommended to install extensions into pg_catalog schema?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107389/is-it-recommended-to-install-extensions-into-pg-catalog-schema/107418#107418)
- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the “current schema”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067777/939860)

Comment: Unfortunately they are in the same schema and search path. There is only one schema and that schema is in the search path where the extension was installed. I wish that was the answer!

Comment: Hrmpf. So anything suspicious from this query maybe? `SELECT oprnamespace::regnamespace, oprleft::regtype, oprname, oprright::regtype
FROM pg_operator WHERE oprname = '<@>';`

Comment: Yeah that comes back with `temp point <@> point` so the operator is loaded/setup. No clue why it's not working.

Comment: Ok. This is weird. Now it's working. I didn't try it before I tried your `pg_operator` query, but I did after and now it seems to work. Not sure why now. Pg wasn't restarted. I did drop/create everything from scratch, but when I tried it after drop/create I received the same error as before. The only difference is that I left the computer for about 45 min. Not sure how that would affect anything especially when I restarted Pg before and it still didn't work. Does `pg_operator` refresh any system metadata?

Comment: `pg_operator` is a system catalog (a plain table). It does not "do" anything. The most obvious explanation would be that the failing session ran with a different `search_path` for some reason. Maybe a setting per role? Details in the 2nd link above.

Comment: It was new temp db for testing out `earthdistance`. No roles or any other users other than the default postgres user for the entire pg server. Operators must have been cached and a pg service restart must not entirely clear the cache. Anyways, thanks for the help!

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer for the time being.

Comment: There *might* be a caching issue in Windows or Postgres then ...