# "Function unaccent(text) does not exist" in update trigger

Tags: postgresql, trigger, unaccent

I've created a trigger for table `x1` to update a column `y` with the expression `to_tsvector(unaccent(x1.col1 || ' ' || x2.col1))`. This trigger function throws:

> ```
> function unaccent(text) does not exist
> ```

Why would this function not exist when a trigger is called, but exist when executed manually? I'm using Supabase to manage this database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `unaccent()` is typically the one installed by the additional module [`unaccent`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/unaccent.html). See:

- [Does PostgreSQL support "accent insensitive" collations?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11007216/939860)

Additional modules can be installed to any schema. (I like to use a dedicated schema.) See:

- [Is it recommended to install extensions into pg_catalog schema?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107389/is-it-recommended-to-install-extensions-into-pg-catalog-schema/107418#107418)

**If** so, then the schema must be added to the [`search_path`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067777/939860) to allow function calls without schema-qualification like you demonstrate.

The obvious explanation for your observation would be that you call the function in one session with an appropriate `search_path`, and execute the trigger in another session with a different `search_path`.

To diagnose, add this line to your PL/pgSQL trigger function just before the command calling `unaccent()` temporarily (and make sure notices are logged or reported to the client, depending on where you look):

```
RAISE NOTICE 'Current search_path: %', current_setting('search_path');
```

The simple & safe fix is to schema-qualify the function name. Like:

```
my_extension_schema.unaccent(text)
```

But investigate whether schemas and the `search_path` are handled properly across your DB cluster ...

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware of the influence of search_path in this case. I thought that these functions were globally accessible.